# Not showing List of Values Field in my Oracle Apex form

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

[image]

There is no option of List of Values between Validation And link field. I want to create LOV in Particular column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There won't be any unless you modify item type to one that actually *contains* list of values, such as

- Select List
- Popup LoV
- Shuttle item

Comment: How to add popup LoV from item to Form or any colume @littlefoot

Comment: As I said: modify item's **type**.

Comment: Problem Solved...@Littlefoot

Comment: Great, I'm glad you did it.